# Silex Captcha returns broken base64 image

Tags: php, html, twig, captcha, silex

I'm using  the silex captcha in my project (kilte/silex-captcha).

I'm fetching the image data via the  following method:

```
$app['captcha.builder']->inline()
```

This returnes e.g. the following string:

```
 data:image/jpeg;base64,PGJyIC8+CjxiPldhcm5pbmc8L2I+OiAgaW1hZ2VqcGVnKCkgZXhwZWN0cyBwYXJhbWV0ZXIgMSB0byBiZSByZXNvdXJjZSwgbnVsbCBnaXZlbiBpbiA8Yj5DOlx4YW1wcFxodGRvY3NccHJvamVrdGVcc2lsZXhcdmVuZG9yXGdyZWd3YXJcY2FwdGNoYVxDYXB0Y2hhQnVpbGRlci5waHA8L2I+IG9uIGxpbmUgPGI+NTY0PC9iPjxiciAvPgo=
```

I try to output the image in my twig template with the following code:

```
<img src="{{ captchaImageCode }}" />
```

The output then is always broken (the final source looks like this):

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,PGJyIC8+CjxiPldhcm5pbmc8L2I+OiAgaW1hZ2VqcGVnKCkgZXhwZWN0cyBwYXJhbWV0ZXIgMSB0byBiZSByZXNvdXJjZSwgbnVsbCBnaXZlbiBpbiA8Yj5DOlx4YW1wcFxodGRvY3NccHJvamVrdGVcc2lsZXhcdmVuZG9yXGdyZWd3YXJcY2FwdGNoYVxDYXB0Y2hhQnVpbGRlci5waHA8L2I+IG9uIGxpbmUgPGI+NTY0PC9iPjxiciAvPgo=" />
```

I'm using a browser that supports base 64 images (FF 41.0.2). It seems like the base64 code is broken ...
What can I do to fix the broken image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decode the base64 to see what is being returned....

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  imagejpeg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\projekte\silex\vendor\gregwar\captcha\CaptchaBuilder.php</b> on line <b>564</b><br />
```

As you can see it is writing the base64 data with a message instead of the actual image.

Answer (score 0):

Try to output [raw](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html) variable in twig:

```
<img src="{{ captchaImageCode | raw }}" />
```

Comment: But your first image string is equal to second string which is inserted into src  of img tag. At least at the example